# Calling the click function for button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am very new to jQuery and HTML. I am trying to create a button in html that uses jQuery to make the button to prompt alert message when clicked (rather than using onclick in html). In other words, I would like to use the jquery to call up the click function for the button and then return a pop up message.

I have my input type as "button" and my value as "Check" for my button in html.

Here's my code in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    alert("Pop Out");
});
```

but nothing is showing up

Here's a fiddle to my code

http://jsfiddle.net/0ynbv233/8/

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with your code? (jsfiddle.net). It sounds like you may have mistaken `button` element with `input` element of /type/ `button`. Try replacing `$("button")` with `$("input[type=button]")` if that's the case.

Comment: Can you also provide your HTML snippet for the element?

Answer (score 1):

> I have my input type as "button"

Like this?

```
<input type="button" />
```

In that case, this won't work:

```
$("button")
```

That selector is looking for `button` elements, not `input` elements.  You can change the element:

```
<button />
```

or you can change the selector:

```
$('input[type="button"]')
```

Comment: The line in my html is

    <td><input type="button" value="Check"></input></td>

will the td tag affect anything?

Comment: @VincentTeo: The `td` doesn't make a difference, no.  The jQuery selector string simply needs to identify the element(s) you're looking for.  In this case your markup is an `input` element, so you need to select that.  Not a `button` element.

Comment: @VincentTeo: The syntax highlighting on jsFiddle indicates that you have an unclosed set of quotes for a string.

Comment: hi, I changed my code to $("input").click(function(){

i also tried $("input type").click(function(){
I also tried $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){


but they doesn't seems to be working too

as for the highlighting syntax, do you mean the red tags like </td> and </tr>?

http://jsfiddle.net/0ynbv233/8/

Comment: @VincentTeo: 1) You forgot to close the function being passed to the `ready` handler.  2) You forgot to include jQuery in the jsFiddle.  See updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/0ynbv233/9/

Answer (score 0):

I did what you have done and it worked for me.

Here is what my code was.

```js
$(function(){
  $("button").click(function () {
    alert("Pop Out");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Hope you figure out what you are doing wrong.